# Add in-between endpoint for identity server external identity provider requests

Tags: identity, identityserver3

We are using identity server3 for login and some users can login using an external identity provider(eid).
In the case of an external identity provider we provide a redirect URL, so once the user login to eip server he comes back to our identity server URL like myauth/myauthentication.

I have added a new endpoint MyCallbackEndpoint using a web API controller which I have to use in-between so that based on the token received from eip I can redirect users to use new custom logic or proceed with the existing flow of the identity server. To proceed with the existing flow I am doing a redirect call with status code 307 so all the parameters in the request are passed to myauth/myauthentication

The problem I am facing is once the user comes back after authentication from eip to new web API endpoint MyCallbackEndpoint and redirecting to myauth/myauthentication I am getting 404, I compared the requests only difference I see in the cookie value and token. I see extra cookies are added. My question is, is it possible to add an in-between endpoint for identity server external identity provider requests

Comment: can you share the request body and URL and headers